# What are the popular API to get current exchange rates for Ethereum to USD

Tags: contract-development, blockchain, ico, exchange-api

Can you please list all the API providers for cryptocurrency to USD

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I recommend **CryptoCompare**: https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/

**Example:**

```
GET https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/price?fsym=ETH&tsyms=BTC,USD,EUR

{"BTC":0.1048,"USD":858.99,"EUR":662.93}
```

Comment: Is there any limit to call it in a day

Comment: 6000 requests per hour per IP

Comment: Can you list API with unlimited or more request per hour

Comment: Capped at 250,000 calls though :/ would work for a while. I have a script that calls it every 5 minutes and displays the value in my terminal. It would work for a little over two years.

Comment: Is it possible to pass an amount in USD and get ETH amount back? or is there a way to calculate amount in ETH given fiat amount? ie: 1USD => ?? ETH?

Answer (score 12):

https://developers.coinbase.com/api/v2#exchange-rates
By coinbase ,I think best api for exchange rates with accurate data

example for ethereum:
https://api.coinbase.com/v2/exchange-rates?currency=ETH

Comment: This is a great universal solution without limits. Should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

I am using Etherscan Api

https://api.etherscan.io/api?module=stats&action=ethprice&apikey=YourApiKeyToken

`{"status":"1","message":"OK","result":{"ethbtc":"0.01861","ethbtc_timestamp":"1566457540","ethusd":"185.73","ethusd_timestamp":"1566457537"}}`

Answer (score 1):

Along with above 2 options, there are more:

1. Coingecko : they have npm module so no integration efforts are needed

https://www.coingecko.com/api/docs/v3#/simple/get_simple_price

2. coinmarketcap

https://coinmarketcap.com/api/documentation/v1/#operation/getV1ToolsPriceconversion